# Set NSPredicate fetchLimit for a day in date range

Tags: core-data

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
```

Say `startDate` is 13/01/2017 and `endDate` is 15/01/2017. I want to limit the request in the way that there will be no more that 10 items returned for each day.

So, if request result is

```
100 items with `date` == 13/01/2017 
2 items with `date` == 14/01/2017 
50 items with `date` == 15/01/2017
```

I need to make it like

```
10 items with `date` == 13/01/2017 
2 items with `date` == 14/01/2017 
10 items with `date` == 15/01/2017
```

I think the only way is to create loop and perform fetch for each day so that number of fetch requests is equal to number of days in given range. Another solution is to perform one fetch and then filter this big array. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. Please can you rephrase/ clarify?

Comment: I've changed my question.

Comment: Thanks - I understand better now.  But I'm afraid I think you're right: you will need to run multiple fetches, one for each day, with fetchLimit set for each.